# Is it a good idea to process JSON to remove field names before transmitting?

Tags: php, json

I'm building a php web service which communicates with a smartphone app using JSON.

The data we're sending to the client looks a bit like this:

```
{
    "events":[
        {
            "event_id": 1,
            "event_name": "Event 1",
            "event_location_id": 1450,
            "event_timestamp": 1367515800
        },
        {
            "event_id": 2,
            "event_name": "Event 2",
            "event_location_id": 131,
            "event_timestamp": 1367515801
        },
        ETC......
    ]
}
```

The entire block of json data we're sending to the client currently totals about 1mb, and is likely to get bigger. It seems to me that most of this data is the same object field names repeated over and over again, which seems redundant to me.

If I was to send the exact same data in the following slightly different format, I estimate we'd only be sending about 20% of the amount of data:

```
{
    "events": {
        "fields":["event_id", "event_name", "event_location_id", "event_timestamp"],
        "items":[
            [1, "Event 1", 1450, 1367515800],
            [2, "Event 2", 131, 1367515801],
            ETC........
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm surprised that I couldn't find anything on the net about this, has anyone else ever tried structuring their JSON in this way? Is the extra processing on the server a worthwhile tradeoff for the much smaller datasize? Is there any data compression generally happening behind the scenes that makes these considerations irrelevant?

Comment: `JSON` is an "human readable" alternative to `XML`. So, it's whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Does it *really* require *"extra"* processing?  In any case, yes it's a worthwhile trade off.  Any processing difference in the structure of the *JSON* is negligible if it's going to reduce the size of the response - bandwidth is and will always be (probably) the most significant bottleneck in any web-app.

Comment: Yeah the first version is pretty much just the results of pdo::fetchAll() stuffed into json_encode(), whereas the second requires manually building the field & item arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a blog post on OData on the different format you mentioned. However, it looks like it didn't get implemented.

http://www.odata.org/blog/an-efficient-format-for-odata/

The different format also turns out to be more efficient CPU wise

http://mailinglist.odata.org/scripts/wa-ODATA.exe?A2=ind1103&L=ODATA&D=0&P=79521

Puzzles me too as to why the format isn't adopted.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches. You can take a look at

[MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/)

and

[HPack](http://search.cpan.org/~gvenkat/JSON-HPack-0.0.2/lib/JSON/HPack.pm)

Although it seems a good idea to pack the data, it may not bring expected results in case of compression.